# Using code snippets contributed by you in a library/project with restrictive license

Tags: licensing, open-source-software, gpl

Years ago I contributed some code snippets to a C++ library released with GPL license. Currently I am working on some closed-source commercial project where these snippets could be very helpful.

1. Could I re-use these snippets to develop my closed-source commercial application without infringing the GPL license?
2. Could I extract the snippets and change the license to something compatible with commercial applications (e.g. MIT license)?

Answer (score 1):

### You don’t need a licence to use your own copyright

Also, you can release your work under as many (or no) licences as you want subject to the limit that you can only exclusively licence it once within the scope of that exclusivity.